# Instanciar un objeto con new Sin asignar a una variable y error al hacer lo mismo con un string

Tags: java

¿Porque en Java puedo instanciar un objeto con new sin asignar esa referencia a una variable mientras que si hago eso con un string me da error, no se supone que string tambien es un objeto que se instancia de manera implicita?

```
new Persona(); 

"Hola mundo";

new Persona().decirAlgo();

"Hola mundo".toUpperCase();
```

Ok,en la primera parte según lo que he estudiado funciona porque lo que estoy haciendo es invocar a una función constructora y no es necesario que almacene lo que me retorne en una variable ya que es una instrucción de invocación pero mi duda esta aqui, ¿No se supone que deberia suceder lo mismo con el string ya que al usar el string se instancia un objeto de manera implicita y por ende estaria llamando a un metodo constructor?

Y en los otros dos ejemplos tampoco no entiendo algo, se que la invocación al método decirAlgo funciona porque la función Constructora me retorna una referencia a ese punto de la ejecución del programa y por ende puedo usar el valor devuelto por esa expresion pero ¿Porque si ahora uso el string para luego invocar al método de la clase String toUpperCase este funciona si cuando trate de usar solo la cadena "Hola mundo" en la instrucción anterior esta me da error porque no debería funcionar igual que cuando invoco a la función constructora usando new en Persona?

Osea que en ese punto en donde esta "Hola mundo" no se esta invocando de manera implícita a un constructor y no obtengo ninguna referencia y por ende no puedo invocar al método de la referencia retornada por el método constructor porque el metodo constructor no se esta llamando pero sin embargo si uso una cadena de junto con un metodo de la clase String este si funciona ¿Alguien podría explicarme exactamente que ocurre?

Comment: Juan, si tienes algun problema editando tu pregunta comentalo aqui y trataremos de ayudarte

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Para explicar esta pregunta podemos hacernos otra antes:

> ¿Por qué podemos instanciar un cadena sin utilizar `new String()`?

En el ejemplo que pones:

```
"Hola mundo";
```

Da error, pero

```
new String("Hola Mundo");
```

No lo da.

El primer caso se llama "Declaración implicita", y tiene una diferencia importante con el segundo caso. En la declaración implicita es posible que no se cree un nuevo objeto, ya que antes se comprueba si existe una cadena exactamente igual en el llamado "String Constant Pool" (Almacen de constantes de cadena), y si es así, en lugar de crear un nuevo objeto se obtiene una referencia al objeto ya existente.

Por eso el primer caso da error. No tiene sentido obtener la referencia a un objeto que no se va a almacenar en ningun sitio. El segundo caso de declaración explícita si, ya que se llama al constructor del objeto (aunque no tenga mucho sentido).

Comment: ¿Entonces lo que ocurre es que en si la cadena se almacena como objeto en memoria pero a diferencia de otros objetos creados a partir de un constructor, es java como tal el encargado de reservar memoria para ese valor sin hacer uso de un constructor como tal? El objeto se construye de manera interna sin tener que invocar a una función constructora como tal, en realidad no llama a un constructor de manera implícita por así decirlo si no que dado el valor que le doy a la variable, Java prepara espacio para el objeto en memoria basado en la clase String?

Comment: el compilador da error en el ejemplo, ya que si bien se pretende crear en memoria no tiene ningún lugar a donde ir pues solo es un valor y no es el resultado de la ejecución de una función que retorna algo a diferencia de crear un objeto a partir de un constructor?

Comment: Gracias a todos por su apoyo!

Comment: Básicamente es eso @JuanMateo. Cuando tu haces una declaración implicita, antes de crear ningun objeto se mira si ya existe uno con exactamente el mismo texto (se hace asi para poder reutilizar estas cadenas y ahorrar memoria). Si existe, se devuelve la referencia. Si no, se llama al constructor.

Comment: @JuanMateo En cuanto a tu segunda pregunta, ten en cuenta que se puede llamar a métodos que no devuelvan valores. En este caso, `toUpperCase`si devuelve un valor, pero imagina que la clase String tuviese un método para escribir la cadena en disco. `"HolaMundo".Escribir()` tendría todo el sentido del mundo. Por eso el compilador no se queja cuando llamas a un método del string (o creas un nuevo objeto) pero si cuando haces una declaración explicita cuyo unico sentido es devolver una referencia.

Comment: @JuanMateo Viendo [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50306053), parece que no está definido como se crea la cadena en caso de que no exista en el pool.

Comment: Vale debo asegurarme de que la instrucción sobre un dato sea propia de una operación que pueda hacer el dato en el lenguaje, en este caso el string puede tener un comportamiento y puede ser asignado como valor a una variable, pero tiene mas sentido usar este string dentro de una variable ya que puede ser usado múltiples veces de esta forma en vez de usarlo de forma literal ya que su referencia se pierde luego de que el método es ejecutado y otro punto es que si bien es correcto que invoque el método de esa manera no tiene sentido si el dato que me devuelve no lo guardo en algún lugar

Comment: Que tal mi análisis?

Comment: @JuanMateo tu análisis es correcto :)

Answer (score 10):

> Esta mañana he ido a por el pan para hacerme los bocadillos del almuerzo, cuando ha sido mi turno he dicho:
>
> - Tres.
> - ¿Tres que? — Pregunta perplejo el panadero.
> - Tres — Insisto.
>
> Mi insistencia no ha surgido efecto, así que me he ido sin pan.

---

Tú estás haciendo lo mismo en tu código, el compilador no sabe que hacer con la cadena `"Hola mundo"` porque es una instrucción que no tiene sentido por si sola de la misma manera que espetar un número en la panadería tampoco tiene sentido en si mismo, habría tenido el mismo efecto escribir `3;`.

Cambiemos la anécdota:

> Esta mañana he ido a por el pan para hacerme los bocadillos del almuerzo, cuando ha sido mi turno he dicho:
>
> - Tres barras de medio.
>
> El panadero, me las da, las pago y me voy dejándolas en el mostrador de la panadería.

El panadero ha entendido mi petición, pero yo no he hecho nada con ella. Eso es lo que hace el código: `"Hola mundo".toUpperCase();`, habría tenido el mismo efecto escribir `3.toString();`

Comment: Grandes ejemplos.

Answer (score 7):

El error que te da cuando haces `"Hola mundo";` es:

> The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable

Está claro ¿no? Definir un string sin asignarlo a una variable no sirve de nada.

En el segundo caso no tienes ningún error y el método `toUpperCase()` se ejecuta pero es lo mismo - no estás asignando el valor que retorna tu método a ninguna variable. Es decir - es inútil.

Answer (score 4):

El error que te devuelve el programa al tener un String sin asignar como ha indicado Evgeni es un mensaje que te manda el compilador para que sepas que tienes código inútil consumiendo memoria ya que no se asigna el String a ningún sitio.

En el caso de `new Person()` es diferente porque al instanciar una clase, en realidad estás llamando a su constructor en el que puedes tener lógica (no muy buena práctica por cierto), por lo que tiene sentido que el compilador sea más laxo en este caso porque no puede asegurar que tu instrucción sea un desperdicio de memoria (aunque muy probablemente lo sea).