# Comportamiento de los String en java

Tags: java, string, poo, objeto

Alguien podría explicarme por qué cuando se crea un String en java estos son considerados objetos pero en ningún momento se realiza una inicialización del objeto (ej:Objeto obj=new Objeto()) y pese a ello se puede acceder a los métodos de dicha clase.

Comment: Responde [esto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/265093/146637) a tu pregunta??

Comment: En otras palablas al hacer esto: String a;//Java crea un puntero. Y al hacer esto: a="hola mundo";// Java crea una clase y asigna la direccion de la clase clase creada al puntero.

Comment: @PabloLozano lee lo que dice Israel-icm. Si modificas tu comentario avisame para eliminar este.

Comment: Vale, duda resulta, gracias por las respuestas.